# How to automatically include associations in Rails to stop querying unnecessarily?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-activerecord

I have a `user`, which `has_one :user_profile`. Each of these users have experience points. Now I have to load the top 10 users and display their gender-specific photos. But the gender is in the `user_profile` model. How do I get the `user_profile` immediately? I'm running through more queries than I think is necessary. Basically I want a `select * from users where user_profile.user_id = user.id` or something to that effect, so when I need to get `user.user_profile.sex`, I don't query the database again. How do I do this?

Currently trying `User.order("experience DESC").limit(limit).offset(offset).joins(:user_profile)` in the model but when I query user.user_profile.sex in the view, I still make queries.

Comment: change `joins` to `includes`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking for is "includes", described in http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/includes

Includes allows for eager loading, reducing 1+n database calls to 2 calls...

Comment: Wow man, thanks. I also added the scope for future use. I should read the guides more!

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called "eager loading", one-to-one association is eager loaded by default, but you better check it.

In case of many-to-one or many-to-many you can request eager loading explicitly via command like this:

```
Client.includes(:address).find(some_id)
# or any other query like
Client.includes(:address).where(id: some_id, name: "Some Name")
```

If you want to always use eager loading without explicitly specifying it in your model you should write:

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :orders, -> { includes :line_items }
end
```

More examples can be found [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) and [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations)